# Как получить ссылку поста из канала telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Мне нужно получать ссылку последнего поста из канала и направлять еë на апи другого сервиса. Отследить появление нового поста и узнать его id у меня, конечно, получилось, но вот сделать из этого ссылку не получилось. Как я понял, telethon блокирует некоторые действия с данными во время сессии. Может, есть некоторые альтернативные способы получить ссылку на пост?

Comment: можете сформировать сами зная параметры https://t.me/%name_or_id_channel%/%number_post%